# Evaluations by elders

Tags: discussion, moderation

Especially toward the moderator team

As an encouragement, for you communities welfare. It would be good if you invite Elders as your evaluators, helpng and supervising the young and not so informed moderator team, not only in regard og knowlege, but also in regard of maturity and knowledge of the tradition as well as importand cultural aspects of which young western are total unaware and cause steady much harm for themselves and many.

My person is not sure whether they would be willing to struggle with young, pride and not very hearing people but it would be of great benefit it they would ask for Nissaya from some of the older members here, maybe some like the Acariyas Upasaka Saptha Visuddhi or Upasaka Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena, both very attentive careful and well informed, yet both with a lityle different background and both liberal enough to build a bridge between those interested and certain faith and those firm in right direction, on the path. When ever you may have traced someone else, look out whether he is of firm faith and also practiced and whether he is praised by wise or not and good if he has a cultural background of the traditional countries and is no trader in Dhamma as layperson (but earns his living rightouse but independent means, aside of Dhamma).

Surely not easy to put oneself into dependency, but that is actually how this tradition ever was proper carried on. Maybe you like to give your many sacrifices more chance to be proper guided and adjusted for the welfare of many.

You need, if you wish for such, in proper way, consciously and personal ask them for such. Otherwise the relation of student-disciple would not be proper and both would not have the task to take their position very serious and responsible for their part, toward father, towrad son.

*(Note that this encouragement is not given for trade exchange, stacks or entertainment, but as a means of proper conducts toward liberation)*

Comment: Nyom Chris, it's not sure that this is not actually a feature request and lesser a matter of moderation since it is about evaluation which requires also in worldly spheres the "installing" of certain supervision above the "business as usual" moderators do anyhow in best ways they can effort. It might even touch such as technical features to be implemented, not only wishes to go after such. For example a way to communicate or a place where supervision can be made without causing moderators to be much public criticized or taught. (as he changed the tags)

Comment: I checked, so I'm pretty sure -- the [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) tag is when you're asking for or suggesting that SE should change the software (i.e. to implement a new feature). SE has some [20,000 feature-request topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) -- and it's my opinion that no "feature-request" would be successful (i.e. that it's not worth asking), especially if the change is only meant for the "Buddhism.SE" site and not of benefit (not relevant) to all the SE sites.

Comment: Instead of proposing a new software feature, I think you're suggesting or wanting to discuss a change to the way in which this Buddhism.SE site is moderated and "supervised", and/or by whom (i.e. "invite Elders as your evaluators, helpng and supervising the young and not so informed moderator team").

Comment: Surely the "feature" thought was in regard of it's meaning in personal interaction at first place, but not sure if such at a whole, is not interesting for a larger, since such as supervision might have it's lack in regard of single areas, Nyom Chris.

Comment: How could a not-moderator communicate more in the back with moderators? Do moderators even have such intern possibility?

Comment: I guess you're asking about a "private" chat room. A moderator can create a private chat room (i.e. which non-moderators can't see) and then invite a specific user into that chat room to discuss something.

Comment: But a non-moderator, supervisor, could'nt get non-public in contact with a moderator, right? And, if understanding, this feature is used under moderators as well, or do they have other tools to coordinate and asisst each other, Nyom Chris?

Comment: Moderators can use e.g. a private chat room to communicate with each other. Non-users can "flag" something if they want to post a short message to a moderator -- see [flagging](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) -- or users can post in a chat room if there's a chat room which a moderator uses regularly (a public chat room, or a private chat room if there's one to which a user has been invited). Some moderators can be contacted by their personal email too, but SE might prefer it if SE-related topics were kept on the SE-controlled platform (e.g. SE chat instead of personal email).

Comment: So at least moderators could install a privat/limited chatroom where they could invite a supervisor and he could always (if not de-invited) contact the mods, right. In that case no technical features would be necessary. In regard of flag: would the moderator know who send the message?

Comment: `In that case no technical features would be necessary.` Correct. `In regard of flag: would the moderator know who send the message?` That depends on what was flagged, and on the type of flag -- [see e.g. here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109696/139866) -- if I'm recalling this correctly, I can't see who flagged a *comment*, though I can often guess who it was from the context. A person could add their name to the flag if they wanted to be sure (or I might be able to recognise some people by what or how they write).

Comment: On other SE sites (where I'm not a moderator), if I wanted to make a suggestion or ask a question, I might have posted on Meta -- or in the site's *public* chat room. On *this* site the public chat room is unused, but that it is how users usually "supervise" an SE site, and/or give feedback to the moderators.

Comment: With the privat chat you would have all ways to follow such suggestion as mentioned in the OP, as far as seen, and such would not even be public at all. So all up to your choices here. Public feedback might be well, but a serious relation has more and proper good effects.