# Proposal: Pali should be on-topic

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, proposed-faq

It was decided -- [here, long ago](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2081/254) and without much discussion -- that Pali (the language) isn't Buddhism and therefore isn't on topic -- though of course the meanings (translations, analysis and so on) of Pali Buddhist texts have always been on-topic.

It's argued [in comments under this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2485/254) that this prohibition does more harm than good -- is unwelcoming to people who might want Q&A about this topic (i.e. Pali), and who might stay to become members of the community in other topics.

So this proposal is that "Pali", as well as "Buddhist Hybrid Sanskrit", should be taken as on-topic here and not closed.

If you have an opinion which decision would be better for the site, please up-vote yes or no.

If you have more to say on this subject you may also post an answer.

Comment: Since questions re Pali at this site would likely be re Romanised Pali, & would likely be to do with Buddhist texts, including them seems beneficial & appropriate!

Comment: And same for Hybrid Sanskrit & similar

Comment: It should be restricted to Pali and Buddhist Hybrid Sanskrit in **romanized** form only.

Comment: Perhaps to avoid abuse, it might be appropriate to prohibit lengthy original or creative works, or require links to one of the several recognized depositories for lengthy texts? Or that discussion include recognizable contemporary languages? Vocabulary and concept discussion might not be problematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

Questions about Pali or Buddhist Hybrid Sanskrit should be on-topic and welcome.

Comment: I can't cast a vote because I was the one who posted this answer and the other one, but I might vote for this one -- what is the harm, what's the worst that could happen?

Answer (score -2):

### No

Let's keep the current policy, that this kind of question isn't on-topic.