# A request to reopen a question

Tags: discussion

My understanding is that this is the "more liberal" moderation policy for this community:
[Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/moderation-policies-for-questions)

According to this  "more liberal" moderation policy, I do not understand why my question was closed and deleted?

"[What are the most common ways to enable keyboards to type Pali characters in 2021? [closed]](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/45693/what-are-the-most-common-ways-to-enable-keyboards-to-type-pali-characters-in-202)"

It was suggested that the question was too technical and that it should be asked in another community.

And yet, in 2021, everything we do is technical and, more importantly, this particular question concerns the technology used to enter questions and answers into **this forum** using characters from the Pali language.

Many members of this community have, at one time or another, struggled with this particular question when trying to figure out how to post questions using the Pali language on various devices.

I submit that it is a reasonable question to ask and that many people would benefit from knowledge sharing.

I submit that this is the correct SE forum in which to ask it because this is the forum with the largest collection of people who are most interested in this particular language.

I agree with the author of the "more liberal" moderation policy and would like to remind fellow practitioners what the Buddha said about such things:

> "While you are doing a bodily action, you should reflect on it: 'This
> bodily action I am doing — is it leading to self-affliction, to the
> affliction of others, or to both? Is it an unskillful bodily action,
> with painful consequences, painful results?' If, on reflection, you
> know that it is leading to self-affliction, to the affliction of
> others, or to both... you should give it up. But if on reflection you
> know that it is not... you may continue with it.”

[Ambalatthika-rahulovada Sutta: Instructions to Rahula at Mango Stone](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.061.than.html)

Allowing this question to be asked to and answered only contributes to merit.

I fail to see how closing it is meritorious.

I would also like to request that those who are eager "rule enforcers" and would like a "less liberal" moderation policy in order to their satiate their sense-desire to inflict their will upon others by practicing their rule enforcement craft to consider the words of the Buddha:

> “Only the self controlled should restrain others.
> Truly it is hard to restrain oneself.”

[Dhammapada, Chapter 12: Oneself](https://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/dhammapada/)

Please re-open the question and/or provide an alternate means by which members of the community can acquire this information from those who possess it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point we decided that questions about Pali language -- e.g. grammar -- is off-topic ...

- Because for example questions about Chinese language are off-topic.
- Because someone studying the language (e.g. its grammar) might have 1000 questions, that aren't very interesting to most people

... but that questions about the *meaning* of Pali Buddhist texts are of course on-topic.

Perhaps your question was closed for this kind of reason: i.e. that it's more about language -- grammar, syntax, script -- than meaning.

---

That said, there's a concept of "forbidden but tolerated" which goes like this for example:

- It's *forbidden* to park your bicycle in the courtyard (because if everyone does that then it's a problem)
- If only one person does it then that's harmless, so that's *tolerated* and the rule isn't enforced
- But if everyone does it and it becomes a problem, then we begin to enforce the rule

I'd suggest that as long as it's just this one question, that seems harmless -- and so I'd be willing to undelete it, if another moderator will agree to.

Comment: In [Proposal: Pali should be on-topic](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492/471), the majority voted that Pali (syntax, grammar etc.) should be on-topic. However, [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/45693/471) seems to be about software and keyboard for Pali, and not Pali language itself. Would this be on-topic if Pali is on-topic?

Comment: @ruben2020 You're right, I'd forgotten we revised that policy about language. But here I'm not trying to vote that all technology questions are on-topic -- I am saying this question is at least adjacent to the topic, and harmless ... and that, especially because there's only one of it (and the fact there were two of it only implies that it's a FAQ and therefore popular/useful), it can be "tolerated" even if not "permitted".

Comment: It doesn't matter to me whether the question is re-opened or if the need is met by some other means. e.g. an FAQ that others can contribute to. But the need to understand how to correctly enter words in the pali language on this forum from a variety of devices is a need that many of us would be grateful to have met by some means.

Comment: @ChrisW OK. Then in that case, I agree that the question can be "tolerated".

Comment: @ruben2020 And it's not only about the topic, it's about the community. A reason why SE sites are segregated by topic (instead of hypothetically one big site for every question on every topic) is so that when you ask a question there's a "community" of users on the site who are able and willing to answer that kind of question. And it seems to me that this question is sufficiently within the "sphere of interest" and "area of expertise" of this site's community.